# Is there a command to list all active maldet scans?

Tags: linux, malware, command

I relatively often run 2 or more scans on a server simultaneously (unfortunately some servers contain many users that manage to get their files infected simultaneously) and on many of those occasions a command that would list how many scans are active and maybe even which directories are currently being scanned would come in mighty handy. Do any of you know if some shorthand code for this is allready at our disposal? Kind regards, David

Comment: Other than `ps`?

Comment: Hi Michael, yes sorry, I meant one that would also show the directory being scanned in the result. If there's a way to make PS show that data I would love to hear about it ofcourse.

Comment: You can certainly see the command line with `ps` but that doesn't mean that the information you want is necessarily in the command line! Depends on what `maldet` does and how you call it, I suppose.